# Delphi Indy IdHTTP Authorization

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I'm trying to get user photos in Exchange using `IdHTTP` through `REST API`

[How to: Get user photos by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190905(v=exchg.150).aspx)

```
procedure TsMain.IdHTTP1Authorization(Sender: TObject;
  Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Authentication.Username := DomainName +'\'+ User;
  Authentication.Username := User + #64 + DomainName;
  Authentication.Password := Password;
  Handled:=true;
end;

function TsMain.GetUserPhoto(const eMail: string):Boolean;
var
  s: TStream;
  ResponseCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  idHTTP:= TIdHttp.Create(Application);
  s := TFileStream.Create('mypic.jpg', fmCreate);
  try
    idHTTP.OnAuthorization := IdHTTP1Authorization;
    idHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(idHTTP);
    idHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    idHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication:= true;
    idHTTP.Get('https://ServerName/ews/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email='+eMail+'&size=HR240x240', s);
    ResponseCode := idHTTP.Response.ResponseCode;
    case ResponseCode of
      200:
        begin
          Result := True;
        end;
    else
       ShowMessage(idHTTP.Response.ResponseText);
    end;
  finally
    s.Free;
    idHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I get `HTTP/1.1 401 Anonymous Request Disallowed`.

Why the `idHTTP` not send the Authentication with request ? What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You should provide the initial user credentials in the `TIdHTTP.Request.Username` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties *before* calling `TIdHTTP.Get()` if you already have them. If the server rejects the credentials, the `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event is fired so you can provide new credentials (such as by prompting the user) and then set `Handled` accordingly (true = retry, false = stop).

Comment: Also look at the `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event, which tells you which authentication schemes the server actually allows. It might not even be allowing `BASIC` authentication to begin with, in which case `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` is useless, you would have to add relevant `IdAuthentication...` units to your `uses` clause (`IdAuthenticationNTLM`, etc) so `TIdHTTP.Request.Authentication` can be populated with the correct class type (if you don't directly assign it manually).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks it works very well as you pointed after assigned `TIdNTLMAuthentication` into `AuthenticationClass` property on `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event. And assigned `False` into `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` property.  Then as you also pointed regarding the **initial user credentials before calling** `TIdHTTP.Get()`  You may added it as answer because its really helped me. i appreciate your help.